# Close "<app> quit unexpectedly" window from terminal/bash

Tags: bash, macos, macos-sierra

Is there a way to close/kill " < app> quit unexpectedly" window from terminal or bash script? What's the process name?

(AppleScript automation solutions are not acceptible.)

Comment: A bit more information could help. You mean the app is running and you want to kill it? If it has already quit unexpectedly then it is gone, what is left to kill?!... OR do you mean that it hangs, i.e., freezes and you want to send it a `SIGKILL`?!

Comment: What is wrong with the applescript? (I mean a shell script using `osascript -e 'tell application "UserNotificationCenter" .... etc....'`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can:

```
killall UserNotificationCenter
```

It will kill the `UserNotificationCenter` (an ALL it's opened windows too), so the message disappears. (Don't worry, the next error message will start is again automatically.)

But, (IMHO) it is better to use the `osascript` command in a form:

```
osascript -l JavaScript <<EOS
... apple-scripting using JavaScript ...
EOS
```

IMHO JavaScript is much easier to understand (for an common programmer) as the "standard" `applescript`.

Comment: This answer really needs scripting code that actually closes all those windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it appearing in the first place by:

```
defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none
```

Other possible values are `developer`<sup>†</sup> (show stack traces for all processes) and `crashreport` (the default).

This also means that no entries will be written to the Console.app though. The dialog itself is shown by the `UserNotificationCenter` and can be disabled (along with many other notifications) by:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.UserNotificationCenter.plist
```

**Some context:**

Mach has a concept of *exception ports*. Each thread/process has a task, process and a host exception port, which are checked when an exception occurs. The CrashReporter daemon registers the host exception port and gets activated when no other signal handler ran. It then creates a stack trace and memory map of the process and instructs the `UserNotificationCenter` to show it. By default it only does so for GUI applications.

---

On High Sierra, I had to use `defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter -string "developer"`

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if apple hast the same core utilities, but I come from the unix world too.

for example: the solution would be to find the process id via name. on my linux system I can use the following to find a process id...

```
ps -aux
```

An other variation would be **top**. both give a ton of information and I have to filter the code with **grep**.
After that I would filter the string via **cut** or **sed**.
last but not least the **kill** command.

the script should look some like this ...

```
#!/bin/sh
PNAME="< app> quit unexpectedly"
ps -aux | grep "$PNAME" | cut -d" " -f2 | kill
```

## but be warned, this script can make huge damage if u dont know how to use it.

To be hornest I would never use some like this, instead would execute **kill** manually..